# jquery <select> dropdown options keeps populating with incorrect data

Tags: javascript, jquery

My response:

```
["abc - def","ghi - jkl","mno - pqr"]
```

My PHP:

```
$final = array();
if(count($data) > 0){
    foreach($data as $datum){
        array_push($final,$datum);
    }
    echo json_encode($final);
}
else
    echo "abcdef";
```

How I am populating my dropdown:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/php_script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "input": "fetch values" },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache:false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response) //doesn't show when response is "abcdef"
        let selectedValue = $select.val();
        let html = response.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i).map(item => `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`);
        $select.html(html).val(selectedValue);
    },
    complete: function() {}
});
```

The dropdown shows as:

```
abc - def
ghi - jkl
mno - pqr
```

which is fine. Now if the response is like this:

```
abcdef
```

the dropdown still shows:

```
abc - def
ghi - jkl
mno - pqr
```

Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: when your response is `abcdef` what is the expected output ?

Comment: The dropdown should be empty.

Comment: Can you tell us why it should be empty ? Also if you manually execute ``['abcdef'].filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i).map(item => `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`)`` you will get `['<option value="abcdef">abcdef</option>']` as a result.

Comment: Only if my response is inside an array`[]` should it show in my dropdown, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

there is two way
first: search comma character in response
second is set `cache:false` in ajax request

Comment: Still not working

Comment: then check the length of array or check is response is array